# ObjectListView - adding new rows

Tags: vb.net, objectlistview

I am writing a tool in vb/windows forms that will delete user profiles on remote computers. It works great except for displaying the computer names and the profiles that were deleted.

When I try ObjectListView it displays the information on the first row and the overwrites it for each computer and each profile deleted on each computer. Here is the part of the code I am having issues with....

```
Public Class PC
    Public Property Computer_Name As String
    Public Property Profile_Name As String
End Class
```

-

```
For Each objProfile In colProfiles
    Dim dtmLastUseTime = CDate(Mid(objProfile.LastUseTime, 5, 2) & "/" &
Mid(objProfile.LastUseTime, 7, 2) & "/" & VB.Left(objProfile.LastUseTime, 4) _
& " " & Mid(objProfile.LastUseTime, 9, 2) & ":" &
Mid(objProfile.LastUseTime, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(objProfile.LastUseTime,
13, 2))
    If DateDiff("d", dtmLastUseTime, d1) > intMaxProfileAge Then
        usrPath = objProfile.localpath
        rowInfo2 = usrPath

        Dim LvItm As New PC With {.Computer_Name = rowInfo1, .Profile_Name = rowInfo2}
        Dim LvLst As New List(Of PC)
        LvLst.Add(LvItm)
        ObjectListView1.SetObjects(LvLst)

        objProfile.Delete_
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Not even one row? because in your code you create each iteration a new list for current item.

Comment: SetObjects() definitely clears the list before adding the new items.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this:

```
Dim LvLst As New List(Of PC)
LvLst.Add(LvItm)
ObjectListView1.SetObjects(LvLst)
```

in:

```
ObjectListView1.AddObject(LvLst)
```

**OR**

move this line

```
Dim LvLst As New List(Of PC)
```

before strat for-each loop, and this line

```
ObjectListView1.SetObjects(LvLst)
```

after the `next` line.

Comment: It adds adds entries for each iteration on the same same row.  What I want to do is add each iteration to a new row.   I will try your suggestions and let you know what happens.